# Tomcat won't load default web page in browser

Tags: java, apache, tomcat

I can't get the default webpage for tomcat to appear. 
The webpage says:

This webpage is not available
ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

I set the port to 8081 in server.xml

```
 <Connector port="8081" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
               connectionTimeout="20000"
               redirectPort="8443" />
    <!-- A "Connector" using the shared thread pool-->
```

I have a launch.bat file that should launch Tomcat when ran in cmd unless I'm misunderstanding how it works. I'm a beginner and have never used Tomcat before.
Here's the deploy.bat file running. Any help is appreciated.

```
 Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.10240]
(c) 2015 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

C:\Users\Joe>cd workspace/TomcatProject/src/week09/week09

C:\Users\Joe\workspace\TomcatProject\src\week09\week09>launch.bat
'launch.bat' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

C:\Users\Joe\workspace\TomcatProject\src\week09\week09>cd..

C:\Users\Joe\workspace\TomcatProject\src\week09>launch.bat

C:\Users\Joe\workspace\TomcatProject\src\week09>setlocal

C:\Users\Joe\workspace\TomcatProject\src\week09>SET TOOLS_HOME=C:\projects\tools\

C:\Users\Joe\workspace\TomcatProject\src\week09>SET TOMCAT_HOME=tomcat\apache-tomcat-8.0.14-windows-x64\apache-tomcat-8.0.14

C:\Users\Joe\workspace\TomcatProject\src\week09>SET JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_45

C:\Users\Joe\workspace\TomcatProject\src\week09>SET CATALINA_HOME=C:\projects\tools\tomcat\apache-tomcat-8.0.14-windows-x64\apache-tomcat-8.0.14

C:\Users\Joe\workspace\TomcatProject\src\week09>C:\projects\tools\tomcat\apache-tomcat-8.0.14-windows-x64\apache-tomcat-8.0.14\bin\startup.bat
Using CATALINA_BASE:   "C:\projects\tools\tomcat\apache-tomcat-8.0.14-windows-x64\apache-tomcat-8.0.14"
Using CATALINA_HOME:   "C:\projects\tools\tomcat\apache-tomcat-8.0.14-windows-x64\apache-tomcat-8.0.14"
Using CATALINA_TMPDIR: "C:\projects\tools\tomcat\apache-tomcat-8.0.14-windows-x64\apache-tomcat-8.0.14\temp"
Using JRE_HOME:        "C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_65"
Using CLASSPATH:       "C:\projects\tools\tomcat\apache-tomcat-8.0.14-windows-x64\apache-tomcat-8.0.14\bin\bootstrap.jar;C:\projects\tools\tomcat\apache-tomcat-8.0.14-windows-x64\apache-tomcat-8.0.14\bin\tomcat-juli.jar"
C:\Users\Joe\workspace\TomcatProject\src\week09>launch.bat

C:\Users\Joe\workspace\TomcatProject\src\week09>setlocal

C:\Users\Joe\workspace\TomcatProject\src\week09>SET TOOLS_HOME=C:\projects\tools\

C:\Users\Joe\workspace\TomcatProject\src\week09>SET TOMCAT_HOME=tomcat\apache-tomcat-8.0.14-windows-x64\apache-tomcat-8.0.14

C:\Users\Joe\workspace\TomcatProject\src\week09>SET JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_45

C:\Users\Joe\workspace\TomcatProject\src\week09>SET CATALINA_HOME=C:\projects\tools\tomcat\apache-tomcat-8.0.14-windows-x64\apache-tomcat-8.0.14

C:\Users\Joe\workspace\TomcatProject\src\week09>C:\projects\tools\tomcat\apache-tomcat-8.0.14-windows-x64\apache-tomcat-8.0.14\bin\startup.bat
Using CATALINA_BASE:   "C:\projects\tools\tomcat\apache-tomcat-8.0.14-windows-x64\apache-tomcat-8.0.14"
Using CATALINA_HOME:   "C:\projects\tools\tomcat\apache-tomcat-8.0.14-windows-x64\apache-tomcat-8.0.14"
Using CATALINA_TMPDIR: "C:\projects\tools\tomcat\apache-tomcat-8.0.14-windows-x64\apache-tomcat-8.0.14\temp"
Using JRE_HOME:        "C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_65"
Using CLASSPATH:       "C:\projects\tools\tomcat\apache-tomcat-8.0.14-windows-x64\apache-tomcat-8.0.14\bin\bootstrap.jar;C:\projects\tools\tomcat\apache-tomcat-8.0.14-windows-x64\apache-tomcat-8.0.14\bin\tomcat-juli.jar"
C:\Users\Joe\workspace\TomcatProject\src\week09>launch.bat

C:\Users\Joe\workspace\TomcatProject\src\week09>setlocal

C:\Users\Joe\workspace\TomcatProject\src\week09>SET TOOLS_HOME=C:\projects\tools\

C:\Users\Joe\workspace\TomcatProject\src\week09>SET TOMCAT_HOME=tomcat\apache-tomcat-8.0.14-windows-x64\apache-tomcat-8.0.14

C:\Users\Joe\workspace\TomcatProject\src\week09>SET JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_45

C:\Users\Joe\workspace\TomcatProject\src\week09>SET CATALINA_HOME=C:\projects\tools\tomcat\apache-tomcat-8.0.14-windows-x64\apache-tomcat-8.0.14

C:\Users\Joe\workspace\TomcatProject\src\week09>C:\projects\tools\tomcat\apache-tomcat-8.0.14-windows-x64\apache-tomcat-8.0.14\bin\startup.bat
Using CATALINA_BASE:   "C:\projects\tools\tomcat\apache-tomcat-8.0.14-windows-x64\apache-tomcat-8.0.14"
Using CATALINA_HOME:   "C:\projects\tools\tomcat\apache-tomcat-8.0.14-windows-x64\apache-tomcat-8.0.14"
Using CATALINA_TMPDIR: "C:\projects\tools\tomcat\apache-tomcat-8.0.14-windows-x64\apache-tomcat-8.0.14\temp"
Using JRE_HOME:        "C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_65"
Using CLASSPATH:       "C:\projects\tools\tomcat\apache-tomcat-8.0.14-windows-x64\apache-tomcat-8.0.14\bin\bootstrap.jar;C:\projects\tools\tomcat\apache-tomcat-8.0.14-windows-x64\apache-tomcat-8.0.14\bin\tomcat-juli.jar"
C:\Users\Joe\workspace\TomcatProject\src\week09>launch.bat

C:\Users\Joe\workspace\TomcatProject\src\week09>setlocal

C:\Users\Joe\workspace\TomcatProject\src\week09>SET TOOLS_HOME=C:\projects\tools\

C:\Users\Joe\workspace\TomcatProject\src\week09>SET TOMCAT_HOME=tomcat\apache-tomcat-8.0.14-windows-x64\apache-tomcat-8.0.14

C:\Users\Joe\workspace\TomcatProject\src\week09>SET JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_45

C:\Users\Joe\workspace\TomcatProject\src\week09>SET CATALINA_HOME=C:\projects\tools\tomcat\apache-tomcat-8.0.14-windows-x64\apache-tomcat-8.0.14

C:\Users\Joe\workspace\TomcatProject\src\week09>C:\projects\tools\tomcat\apache-tomcat-8.0.14-windows-x64\apache-tomcat-8.0.14\bin\startup.bat
Using CATALINA_BASE:   "C:\projects\tools\tomcat\apache-tomcat-8.0.14-windows-x64\apache-tomcat-8.0.14"
Using CATALINA_HOME:   "C:\projects\tools\tomcat\apache-tomcat-8.0.14-windows-x64\apache-tomcat-8.0.14"
Using CATALINA_TMPDIR: "C:\projects\tools\tomcat\apache-tomcat-8.0.14-windows-x64\apache-tomcat-8.0.14\temp"
Using JRE_HOME:        "C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_65"
Using CLASSPATH:       "C:\projects\tools\tomcat\apache-tomcat-8.0.14-windows-x64\apache-tomcat-8.0.14\bin\bootstrap.jar;C:\projects\tools\tomcat\apache-tomcat-8.0.14-windows-x64\apache-tomcat-8.0.14\bin\tomcat-juli.jar"
C:\Users\Joe\workspace\TomcatProject\src\week09>
```

Comment: seems like your tomcat isn't starting for some reason. You'll find log files in the `log` directory (that would be `C:\projects\tools\tomcat\apache-tomcat-8.0.14-windows-x64\apache-tomcat-8.0.14` in your case). Have a look in there and see what errors it reports.

Comment: The log file is too big so I put it in a pastebin. http://pastebin.com/n3U0rbU3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Likely you haven't stopped Tomcat since you modified your `server.xml` configuration. The log file contains a successful start of tomcat initially, then several failed starts due to "bind failed" which typicially means tomcat is still running. So stop it, then restart it and it should work.

Comment: OMG that worked! Thank you so much. I've been stuck on this for a week now.